# Adding data to multiple tables in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, formhelper

I'm working on an invoicing system, and I'm trying to add invoices in a single form. Right now I'm only getting the ability to add to my invoices table, not my invoices_works table. Here is what I'm working with. Sorry in advance for adding so much code:

My invoices table:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`commission` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '30',
`location_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `location_id` (`location_id`),
CONSTRAINT `invoices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My invoices_works table:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices_works` (
`invoice_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`work_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `invoice_id` (`invoice_id`),
KEY `work_id` (`work_id`),
CONSTRAINT `invoices_works_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`work_id`) REFERENCES `works` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `invoices_works_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`invoice_id`) REFERENCES `invoices` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My works table:

```
CREATE TABLE `works` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` text NOT NULL,
`cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My Invoice Model (the HABTM, at least):

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Work' => array(
                    'className' => 'Work',
                    'joinTable' => 'invoices_works',
                    'foreignKey' => 'invoice_id',
                    'associationForeignKey' => 'work_id'
                )
        );
```

The method for adding in the Controller:

```
public function add() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Invoice->create();
        if ($this->Invoice->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('The invoice has been saved.'), true);
            echo var_dump($this->data);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('The invoice could not be saved.', true));
        }
    }
    $work = $this->Work->find('list');
    $location = $this->Location->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Location.id !=' => 0)));
    $this->set('works', $work);
    $this->set('locations', $location);
}
```

And finally, the View itself:

```
<?php

 echo $this->Form->create('Invoice');
echo "<fieldset>";
    echo $this->Form->input('location_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('commission', array('default' => 30));
echo "</fieldset>";
    //echo $this->Form->hidden('InvoiceWork.invoices_id', array('default' => 1));
echo "<fieldset>";
    echo $this->Form->input('InvoicesWork.work_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('InvoicesWork.count', array('default' => 1));
echo "</fieldset>";

 echo $this->Form->end('Save Invoice');

?>
```

It seems like I'm missing something, and I know it's going to be obvious once I find it.

Comment: It seems like you are looking for [saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array) instead of just save().

Comment: Yup, or `saveAssociated()` http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

Comment: A suggestion to improve the performance of your action; move the `$this->Work->find('list')` ... `$this->set(....)` part of your code to the *end* of your action. These queries are only used if no form is submitted or if the Save failed. By putting them at the start, they will always be executed, even if their results are not used.

Comment: And, while I'm at it, are you using CakePHP 2.x? If so, $this->data is only present for backwards compatibility. Use `$this->request->data` in stead, and check if a form has been submitted via `if($this->request->is('post'){....}`

Comment: I've made those changes, but I'm still not getting anything saved to the invoices_works table. Do I need a Controller and a Model for that table? (I've also tried both saveAll() and saveAssociated(). I've used var_dump to get the array I'm building with the forms.

array(2) { ["Invoice"]=> array(2) { ["location_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["commission"]=> string(2) "30" } ["InvoicesWork"]=> array(2) { ["work_id"]=> string(1) "3" ["count"]=> string(1) "1" } }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of smashing my face against my keyboard, I've solved my issue. I ended up using separate add functions for the two tables.

```
public function add() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Invoice->create();
        if ($invoice = $this->Invoice->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('The invoice has been saved.'), true);
            if(!empty($invoice)) {
                $this->request->data['InvoicesWork']['invoice_id'] = $this->Invoice->id;

                $this->Invoice->InvoicesWork->save($this->request->data);
                echo "InvoicesWork save completed?<br/>";
                echo var_dump($this->request->data);
            }
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('The invoice could not be saved.', true));
        }
    }
    $work = $this->Work->find('list');
    $location = $this->Location->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Location.id !=' => 0)));
    $this->set('works', $work);
    $this->set('locations', $location);
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution, but after I insert data into my invoices table, I grab the new id from it and store it in my array. Then, I just call the add function from the InvoicesWork Model.